# Remove WordPress front page rel next

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone know how to remove default WordPress front page rel next and add custom rel next.
below rel next is wrong.because i am using pagination on my front page.

```
<link rel='next' title='About Us' href='http://myweb/about-us' />
```

i want to correct  my rel next.any one can help me.

```
 <link rel='next' href='http://myweb/page/2' />
```

using **add_action** , and **remove_action**

Comment: From where? Navigation? Content? Sidebars?... be specific.

Answer (score 1):

**Recommended method:**
I'm not sure that `add_action` and `remove_action` are the right tools for this, but since you are willing to use them, you should be willing to use [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) - which **is** the right tool.

There are two filters that you can hook into:

```
add_filter( "previous_post_rel_link", 'remove_title_from_previous_link' );  
add_filter( "next_post_rel_link", 'remove_title_from_next_link' );
```

Then, write your function to parse / remove the title attribute:

```
function remove_title_from_previous_link($link) {
    // Write your code here to provide and return the correct link
    // Sample only below:   
    return '<a href="my_custom_url" title="Corrected Url" rel="previous">';
}

function remove_title_from_next_link($link) {
    // Write your code here to provide and return the correct link
    // Sample only below:   
    return '<a href="my_custom_url" title="Corrected Url" rel="next">';
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you really must use `add_action` and `remove_action`, then you'd want to hook into this action like so:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 999);
```

And then

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_rel_link_function');
```

And of course your custom function:

```
function my_custom_rel_link_function() {
    // ... do your magic here ...
}
```

Comment: really thank you for your reply.but this is not working on front page.

Comment: Thnak you. 
i change like this.
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

Answer (score 0):

**This is Only for Front Page**

add below code in to the head section

```
// add custom link rel for home page
if(is_front_page()){
    $post_per_page = 1;
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
    $published_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
    $prev_link  =   get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 );
    $next_link  =   get_pagenum_link( $paged +1 );

    if( $paged >= 2 ){
        echo "<link rel=\"prev\" href=\"".$prev_link."\"/>"."\n";
    }
    if( $published_posts > ( $post_per_page * $paged ) ){
        echo "<link rel=\"next\" href=\"".$next_link."\"/>"."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution below:**

This removes `rel="next"` & `rel="prev"` from custom post types and pages.

Add below code in `function.php`

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_next_rel_link', '__return_false' );

add_filter( 'wpseo_prev_rel_link', '__return_false' );
```